# HTTP Endpoint service in AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an HTTP server written in C# which receives packets from a certain open port and stores the packets in AWS SQS (Simple Queue Service). Currently this server application in running on an EC2 instance. but, using a whole EC2 instance only for this server application seems meaningless to me. Is there any other AWS service which will do the job?

p.s- I thought of using Lambda once but, seems like it doesn't support elastic IP or, DNS and also I don't need a lot of computation to get the job done.

Comment: Did you check this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/create-api-resources-methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda

This combo fits exactly for your requirement

Comment: Yep this will fit best for your needs. Note however - if there's a high volume on your EC2 - then the above suggestion is not recommended in terms of cost.

Comment: Yes @johni that'll do my job. Thanks a lot **Arafat** for saving me.